# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row, calculate difference between two revisions

Tags: sql, oracle

my query is as follows:

```
select distinct p.CONTRACTNUM  as Contract,c.NAME as Name,
    (select 
        (select trunc(enddate) from maximo.contract where revisionnum = revisionnum ) - 
        (select trunc(enddate) from maximo.contract where revisionnum = revisionnum-1 )
     from dual) as "Current Value Variation"
From Maximo.Purchview P
JOIN  Maximo.Expedite E   
  ON  P.Contractnum=E.Maxid 
JOIN  Maximo.Companies C
  ON  C.Company=P.Vendor 
Where E.Maxapp='CP'
  And P.status ='EXCUTE'
  And P.ENDDATE>sysdate
order by P.Contractnum;
```

I am getting an exception ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
have to calculate difference between two revisions for same record and located in "Current Value Variation" column..

for who asking for sample Output should be like :

```
Contract    Name             Revision   End Date       Value Variation      
 123        Sample Name       0           25-Dec-19     0
 123        Sample Name       1           25-Jun-20     183
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.  A simpler query is also helpful.

Comment: "`where revisionnum = revisionnum`" -- I guess one `revisionnum` is meant to be from an outer table but since there's no qualification and binding always uses the most local table that expression is always true for any existing row. Qualify all columns.

Answer (score 0):

I am infering that the table maximo.contract contains the CONTRACTNUM and can be used to filter the subquery to one result per row

```
select distinct p.CONTRACTNUM  as Contract,c.NAME as Name,
    (select 
        (select trunc(enddate) from maximo.contract a where revisionnum = revisionnum and a.CONTRACTNUM  =  p.CONTRACTNUM) - 
        (select trunc(enddate) from maximo.contract a where revisionnum = revisionnum-1 and a.CONTRACTNUM  =  p.CONTRACTNUM)
     from dual a ) as "Current Value Variation"
From Maximo.Purchview P
JOIN  Maximo.Expedite E   
  ON  P.Contractnum=E.Maxid 
JOIN  Maximo.Companies C
  ON  C.Company=P.Vendor 
Where E.Maxapp='CP'
  And P.status ='EXCUTE'
  And P.ENDDATE>sysdate
order by P.Contractnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select trunc(enddate) from maximo.contract where revisionnum = revisionnum
```

Does not correlate one `revisionnum` to the nested query and then other `revisionnum` to the outer query; it will use the `revisionnum` in the local scope for both and will return every row. Use the table aliases to specify where you want the `revsionnum` to apply to:

```sql
select distinct
    p.CONTRACTNUM as Contract,
    c.NAME as Name,
    ( select trunc(enddate)
      from   maximo.contract c1               -- Add table alias
      where  c1.revisionnum = p.revisionnum   -- use aliases
    ) - 
    ( select trunc(enddate)
      from   maximo.contract c2               -- Add table alias
      where  c2.revisionnum = p.revisionnum-1 -- use aliases
    ) as "Current Value Variation"
From Maximo.Purchview P
JOIN  Maximo.Expedite E   
  ON  P.Contractnum=E.Maxid 
JOIN  Maximo.Companies C
  ON  C.Company=P.Vendor 
Where E.Maxapp='CP'
  And P.status ='EXCUTE'
  And P.ENDDATE>sysdate
order by P.Contractnum;
```

*(Assuming `revisionnum` is in `PurchView`, if not then use the correct alias as we don't have that information.)*

If you need to further correlate the contract to the `PurchView` then add that to the nested query's filter conditions:

```sql
select distinct
    p.CONTRACTNUM as Contract,
    c.NAME as Name,
    ( select trunc(enddate)
      from   maximo.contract c1               -- Add table alias
      where  c1.revisionnum = p.revisionnum   -- use aliases
      and    c1.contractnum = p.contactnum    -- add additional filters
    ) - 
    ( select trunc(enddate)
      from   maximo.contract c2               -- Add table alias
      where  c2.revisionnum = p.revisionnum-1 -- use aliases
      and    c2.contractnum = p.contactnum    -- add additional filters
    ) as "Current Value Variation"
From Maximo.Purchview P
JOIN  Maximo.Expedite E   
  ON  P.Contractnum=E.Maxid 
JOIN  Maximo.Companies C
  ON  C.Company=P.Vendor 
Where E.Maxapp='CP'
  And P.status ='EXCUTE'
  And P.ENDDATE>sysdate
order by P.Contractnum;
```